# Material-ui Stepper. Сan`t make horizontal scroll

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, stepper

I am trying to do horizontal scrolling for stepper on small screens.
Here is my code:

Styles:

```
stepperContainer: {
   width: "100%",
   maxWidth: 950,
   overflow: "scroll",
   backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
},
stepper: {
   minWidth: 500,
   width: "100%",
},
```

Stepper:

```
<div className={classes.stepperContainer}>
 <Stepper
   activeStep={activeStep}
   alternativeLabel
   className={classes.stepper}
   connector={<ColorlibConnector />}
 >
   {...STEPS}
 </Stepper>
</div>
```

And it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem; the scroll bar shows up for me on small screen sizes. Might be a good idea to create a code sandbox.